REST API filter by date giving "The expression is not valid"
I am trying to get a list of old files from our SharePoint online site via REST API but keep getting error:

"The expression is not valid"

I tried the following links with same error:
https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items$filter=Created le datetime'2017-12-06T18:30:00Z'
https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items$filter=Created le '@{addDays(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'AUS Eastern Standard Time'),2,'yyyy-MM-dd')}'
https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items$filter=Created le '2017-12-06'

Any idea how to get it working?

I think you forgot to add question mark ( ? ) after /items in the SharePoint REST API endpoint.
This should work for you:
https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$filter=Created le datetime'2017-12-06T18:30:00Z'

Reference: Filter Created in SP REST API

Shame on me :(
Thanks Ganesh :)

No worries, it happens sometimes. Glad you got it working now.
